# Does cudaDeviceSynchronize() synchronize with other processes too?

Tags: cuda

If I call `cudaDeviceSynchronize()` in my own code, but another separate process is running an unrelated task in the GPU, does my call not return until the GPU finishes the other unrelated tasks too?

Answer (score 1):

If by process you mean threads, then yes. cudaDeviceSynchronize makes the host (the CPU) wait until ALL the threads on the device (GPU) have finished executing. Now your program on the CPU will continue sequentially.

Comment: No, I mean by process - if the system display driver, for instance, decides to do some processing just before my call to `cudaDeviceSynchronize()`, will I wait until the system display driver has finished?

Comment: GPU activity from independent processes is serialized (an exception could be if CUDA MPS was active.)  A `cudaDeviceSynchronize()` from process A knows nothing about the activity from process B.  However, if process B is using the GPU (for whatever reason - whether it is CUDA, or graphics), and you issue a `cudaDeviceSynchronize()` in process A, you may witness an overall latency which includes whatever work occurs in process B until the context switch to process A, followed by whatever CUDA activity has been issued in process A prior to the issuance of `cudaDeviceSynchronize()`.